# Dell Inspiron 3650 back from sleep issue

Tags: display, sleep, dell-inspiron

Just recently, whenever I resume from sleep, I get a bunch of vertical lines on the screen, like this:
[image]
I have to power off and power it back on and it's fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: It might help if you told us what OS you are running.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.  The problem is due to Intel graphics driver 22.20.16.4771 released on 8/13/17. It was just installed in my computer 10/10/17.

The solution is to open device manager and select Display adapter-Intel(R) HD Graphics 530. Open driver tab and click "roll back driver."
My previous driver is version 21.20.16.4542 released on 10/24/16. It works fine.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the info. I'll keep it mind in the future. I had searched and found some people saying about updating the bios, so I did that and it works fine now. It was just wear that it happened out of the blue.